# What in the world is a Zen Simulator?

Tags: dos, simulator, zen

I stumbled upon a really simple but interesting program called ["robotfindskitten"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotfindskitten), and apparently it is a Zen simulator. Everyone who likes the program seems to be throwing the term around like it's some well-known jargon, yet I have no idea what it means. I can, however, hypothesize from the name that it is some reflection of Zen teachings (do not aim, instead let "it" guide you). This makes sense, as you are walking around aimlessly only hoping that one of the ASCII characters is going to be a kitten. But that still does not shed light onto what separates a Zen simulator from, well, a not Zen simulator.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with software development - voted to close. Perhaps could be moved to the English Language and Usage site: http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is a kind of program... Is it not?

Comment: But your question only concerns the semantics of its name. It has nothing to do with the code.

Comment: While this is a *wonderful* question, it unfortunately is not appropriate for StackOverflow. [English](http://english.stackexchange.com) seems like your best bet, and [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or possibly (but maybe not) [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Aspiring young Robot sought its master one day. "Sensei," it asked, "What is the meaning of life?"

The master looked Robot straight in the eye, took a deep breath, and said, "I am your sensei, my young friend, but I am not kitten. Before I can answer your question, you must find kitten."

Young Robot heeded its master's words, wandering the screen in search of kitten. And -- lo! -- one day it did find kitten, and it felt much love and satisfaction. And yet a pressing question still remained in its robot brain.

Robot -- no longer young -- took kitten in its arms and went back to show the master its proud accomplishment, and finally get the answer to its question. But the master was nowhere to be found. He had moved on, perhaps to a console screen many miles away, or maybe to the Big Console Screen In The Sky.

Despairingly, Robot cried out, "Without my master, how can I understand the meaning of life?!"

Kitten purred.

Robot was enlightened.